# What is the total running time of the following code (N is an int variable)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, cumulative-sum

I am preparing for the exam, where I came to this question:

What is the total running time of the following code (N is an int variable)

```
Z z = new Z(N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) z.insert("Bob", i);
```

Class Z:

```
public class Z
{
     String[] names;
     Integer[] numbers;
     int N = 0;

     public Z(int cap)
     {
        names = new String[cap];
        numbers = new Integer[cap];
     }


     public Integer find(String S)
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (names[i].equals(S)) return numbers[i];
        }
        return null;
     }

    public void insert(String S, Integer M)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (names[i].equals(S)) numbers[i] = M;
        }
        names[N] = S;
        numbers[N] = M;
        N++;
    }
}
```

I think the answer for this question is O(n^2). The first for loop takes O(n) times, and the method insert takes O(n) times (notice: n++ on every insert call), which total gives O(n^2)

Comment: You can't calculate the running **time**, you can only find the running time **growth**. You cannot translate a Big-O notation to **time**, that is simply impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that the **N** variable in the main part is not the same as the **N** referenced within the object instance.

After the **z** object is created, its private **N** member is equal to 0 and only increases with every call to `insert`.

So the number of times the loop in the `insert` method iterates is equal to the number of previous calls made to the `insert` method.

So the total number iterations made in the `insert` method (taking all the **N** calls together) is:

**Σ<sub>i=0..N-1</sub> (i)**

This is equal to:

**½N(N-1)**

which is **½N² - ½N** and thus **O(n²)**